# Re-install stock Net-SNMP?

Tags: macos, snmp, refresh

Apologies in advance if this has been answered.

What is the exact procedure to reset Net-SNMP to "factory defaults" on, say, OSX 10.10 - or any other OSX flavor?

A number of our Xserves were upgraded from 10.6 to 10.8 to 10.9 or 10.10 and in the process appear to have their Net-SNMP executables and/or configuration corrupted - e.g. snmpd daemons crashing frequently, not reporting CPU/mem loads, etc. Tried comparing folder structures between affected and unaffected nodes and haven't gotten too far.

**Edit**: just to be clear, this isn't about snmpd.conf - but about snmp executables, MIBs and what not.

Appreciate any ideas!

Comment: There may be issues with the LMSensors MIB on the Xserve hardware

Answer (score 1):

The canonical method to reset a net-snmp installation to factory defaults in Mac OS X (there's no difference between client & server in this case) is:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.net-snmp.snmpd.plist
sudo cp /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf.default /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf
sudo rm /usr/share/snmpd.conf
sudo rm -rf /var/db/net-snmp
```

This resets the snmpd.conf file to the default & clears out any added users and instance data. This should be valid back to 10.6 or so, possibly earlier, but I'm not sure.

In 10.11.x Apple updated the net-snmp version from 5.6 to 5.6.2.1 which may cause some issues.

Comment: Thank you - that didn't help me with the issue - but may be useful in the future.

Comment: Sorry if that did not help. Are all the versions of the OS affected in the same way? i.e. all the machines upgraded to 10.10 from 10.6 are failing while the ones upgraded from 10.8 to 10.10 are fine.

Comment: Some. More details here: https://thwack.solarwinds.com/thread/78738.

The issue went away and/or is no long worth pursuing as our older affected Mac OS hosts have been taken offline, and we're looking into using something other than SNMP for monitoring / alerting. Thanks for the response Leland!

Answer (score 0):

After recent OSX upgrades (10.9 and 10.10 desktop versions, not OSX Server, behaviour might be different) I usually control Net-SNMP configuration in two different places:

- `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf` which should contain your configuration but sometimes get replaced by the default one from OSX
- `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.net-snmp.snmpd.plist` which can disable snmpd launch (look at the `Disabled` key)

I've never seen anything else being replaced (executables, libraries, etc.).

From 10.6 to 10.10 the Net-SNMP version used might be quite different, so you'll also need to double check your `snmpd.conf` file to see if all directives are still valid.  The `snmpconf` utility might come handy, have a look at its man page.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, "What is the exact procedure to reset Net-SNMP to "factory defaults" on, say, OSX 10.10 - or any other OSX flavor?"

snmpd.conf files are the same across OSX nodes.